# PHPMailer warnings

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am currently gobsmacked and so ridiculously confused at the stupidity of this error. It honestly makes no sense to me.

So I have a network of 4 websites all using the same contact.php script which is pasted blow.

So on three of the sites, the script works perfectly. However on one of the sites, it keeps popping up errors. There shouldn't be any errors at all since they are on the same server and using exact same html files except for different content.

```
Warning: include(../../vip/boss/mailer/class.phpmailer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php on line 2

Warning: include(../../vip/boss/mailer/class.phpmailer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../../vip/boss/mailer/class.phpmailer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php on line 2

Warning: include(../../vip/boss/mailer/class.smtp.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php on line 3

Warning: include(../../vip/boss/mailer/class.smtp.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../../vip/boss/mailer/class.smtp.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php on line 3

Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php on line 27
```

Please Help Me

```
<?php
include("../../vip/boss/mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
include("../../vip/boss/mailer/class.smtp.php");
function heal($str) {
$injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
'/(\r+)/i',
'/(\t+)/i',
'/(%0A+)/i',
'/(%0D+)/i',
'/(%08+)/i',
'/(%09+)/i'
);
$str= preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
return str_replace('@','-AT-',$str);
} 
$name = heal($_POSTname);
$email = str_replace('-AT-','@',heal($_POSTemail));
$message = heal(str_replace("\n",'<br>',$_POSTmessage));
$category = heal($_POSTcategory);
if(substr_count($email,'@')==1){
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
$mail->Host       = "localhost";  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";     
$mail->Port       = 465;   
$mail->Username   = "autonote@justevents.net.au";  
$mail->Password   = "REDACTED";          
$mail->From       = "autonote@justevents..net.au";
$mail->FromName   = $name;
$mail->Subject    = $category.' Enquiry';
$mail->Body       = $message;           
$mail->WordWrap   = 50;
$mail->AddAddress("admin@justevents..net.au","justevents. Enquiry");
$mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
header("LOCATION:quicksuccess.html");
} 
}else{
echo 'There was an error, please try again. '.substr_count($email,'@');
} 
?>
```

Comment: I would suggest that the paths are wrong somehow.  Does ` /home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php` exist on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the files you try to include can not be found. So the question is not only if you use the same php script in all four of them, but are they in the same directory? If not, do they have the same directory structure above them? You are using relative paths there for your include, so I guess you just have this version in a subdir or something, so it can not find the files to include from its working directory.

Comment: Well in each php script, they point to the same file. That's the crazy thing. The 3 other scripts can detect/find the file using the same code except for this one.

Comment: Could you give the full directory paths of each of the four files?

Comment: Does `/home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php` exist on your server?

Comment: @user1502697 In php it's sometimes tricky to get the real current working directory, if you do some cross directory including. You could try to make all 4 of them print out the current working dir, to be on the save side there

Comment: @EricJ. I have changed the justevents url so the real url doesn't get picked up on google.

The full directories go like this -

home/aap/public_html/justevents.net.au/quickcontact.php
home/aap/public_html/justfestivals.net.au/quickcontact.php
home/aap/public_html/justpromotion.net.au/new/quickcontact.php
home/aap/public_html/juststaff.net.au/quickcontact.php

Comment: The one that's throwing the error wouldn't happen to be the third one, would it? Just stating the obvious.

Comment: No its not, wish it was because would make the problem much simpler.

Comment: ust got it working!!!!

Changed it from

include("../../vip/boss/mailer/class.phpmailer.php");

to

include("../vip/boss/mailer/class.phpmailer.php");

Comment: You should probably accept @kratenko's answer then because that's what he was saying :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Use [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) on the calling file to debug this sort of errors.**

As you can tell by the logs the documents are not in the path they were expected to be.
There is only one way to be sure, use an absolute path.

And then debug the situation with `getcwd()`...